# Example function on a webpage returns undefined when I run it myself

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

On [this](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html) javascript teaching page, there is the following function:

```
function getHalfOf(num1, num2, num3)     
{ 
  function calculate(number)
  {
    return number/2;
  }

  var result="";
  result+=calculate(num1)+" ";
  result+=calculate(num2)+" ";
  result+=calculate(num3);
}         
var resultString=getHalfOf(10,20,30);
alert(resultString);
```

When I run it in the webpage with their "run example" button, it returns "5 10 15" as expected. However when I run the exact same code externally (in Brackets with live preview) it returns undefined.

Comment: Probably because `alert()` returns `undefined`. Does the Brackets live preview create a popup with the correct answer before exiting?

Comment: not sure what i am missing but this function does not return anything,  makes it return `undefined`  you need to `return result;` before closing the function;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `getHalfOf`.

Put `return result;` as the last line in the `getHalfOf` function:

```
function getHalfOf(num1, num2, num3)     
{ 
  function calculate(number)
  {
    return number/2;
  }

  var result="";
  result+=calculate(num1)+" ";
  result+=calculate(num2)+" ";
  result+=calculate(num3);
  return result; // Insert this line
}         
var resultString=getHalfOf(10,20,30);
alert(resultString);
```

Comment: @user331636 Lerouche's answer is exactly right. If nothing is `returned` at the end of the function, you'll get an undefined. The reason you were seeing the correct values in the browser environment, is because the javascript interpreter built-in to whatever browser you're using can handle the `alert()` method (and show your results), whereas in Brackets, you don't have the browser interpreter, and `alert` messages cannot be displayed. Thus, the only way to see your result is to return it in your original function.

Comment: natureminded Can you expand on that? Why does it work differently in the browser? How is the browser able to "guess" what return value the function should give?

Answer (score 0):

use `return result`in `getHalfOf` function and better use `calculate` function as a global

```js
function getHalfOf(num1, num2, num3) {
  var result = "";
  result += calculate(num1) + " ";
  result += calculate(num2) + " ";
  result += calculate(num3);
  return result;
}
  function calculate(number) {
    return number / 2;
  }
var resultString = getHalfOf(10, 20, 30);
console.log(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line in getHalfOf() needs to be `return result;` so that the variable is returned to the calling function.